# I want to add elements in the list

Tags: python

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to add like this :

```
1+2=3, 2+3=5, 3+4=7, 4+5=9
```

I tried below code but it gives nothing

```py
num_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
n=6 
i=0
j=0
new=[]
count=0
list_len=len(num_list)
for i in range (0,1,list_len-1):
    for j in range (1,1,list_len-1):
        pair=num_list[i]+num_list[j]
        print (pair)
```

expected output :

```
3
5
7
9
11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i in range(len(num_list)-1):
    print (num_list[i] + num_list[i+1])
```

output:

```
3
5
7
9
11
```

Answer (score 2):

Stitch the list with itself offset by one to make the pairs; then just add them together.

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(num_list, num_list[1:])]
# => [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy with just bult in functions:

```
list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

for i in range(len(list) - 1):
  print(list[i] + list[i + 1])
```

output:

```
3
5
7
9
11
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) is designed for this:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

You can either create `list` for just print:

```
[sum(p) for p in pairwise(l)]
# [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
# or

for p in pairwise(l):
    print(sum(p))
```

Output:

```
3
5
7
9
11
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution could be more "pythonic" but it is quite understandable!

```
num_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
results_list=[]
for i in range (len(num_list)):
    if(i==len(num_list)-1):
       break
    results_list.append(num_list[i]+num_list[i+1])

print(results_list)
```

With an output of:

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_arr = [arr[i] + arr[i+1] for i,v in enumerate(arr) if i < len(arr)-1]
print(new_arr)
```